# How to find steps with Google Fit API for Android?

Tags: java, android, api, google-fit

I have done a couple of days of research regarding this. All I need is a Simple TextView area in my application to display today's steps.

I have managed to get the Authentication working with the code below. It pops up asks for permission and think I have the right one selected.

But I can not figure out how to simple gain the Step Count information. I hope this is only a couple of lines of code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT 1: I just need to get the Step count number. I can figure out how to display it later. I also have Toasts in just to help me figure out what is going on.

```
private void buildFitnessClient() {
    if (mClient == null) {
        mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(
                        new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Connected!!!");
                                // Now you can make calls to the Fitness APIs.
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                                // If your connection to the sensor gets lost at some point,
                                // you'll be able to determine the reason and react to it here.
                                if (i == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                } else if (i
                                        == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                    Log.i(TAG,
                                            "Connection lost.  Reason: Service Disconnected");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                )
                .enableAutoManage(this, 0, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                                result.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Google Play services connection failed. Cause: " +
                                result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `HistoryAPI` for Google Fitness API.
FYI: https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#read_data) from Google on how to read the data from Fit:

```
// Setting a start and end date using a range of 1 week before this moment.
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = new Date();
cal.setTime(now);
long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
Log.i(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
        // The data request can specify multiple data types to return, effectively
        // combining multiple data queries into one call.
        // In this example, it's very unlikely that the request is for several hundred
        // datapoints each consisting of a few steps and a timestamp.  The more likely
        // scenario is wanting to see how many steps were walked per day, for 7 days.
        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
        // Analogous to a "Group By" in SQL, defines how data should be aggregated.
        // bucketByTime allows for a time span, whereas bucketBySession would allow
        // bucketing by "sessions", which would need to be defined in code.
        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build();
```

**History API Sample app on GitHub:**

Check the sample project on GitHub [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/tree/master/BasicHistoryApi).

Direct link to `MainActivity.java` (in the above sample project) containing the required code: [Link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/blob/master/BasicHistoryApi/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basichistoryapi/MainActivity.java)

Comment: Ok tired this and it does not bring back any errors. After this I used this code to pass it into a result. DataReadResult dataReadResult =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES); I still cant pass this into a TextView or even a toast though.

Comment: Did it get you the data?

Comment: I have no idea how to check. How can I read the Data Result . I tried this but had no luck as I cant pass a dataset into it. https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#read_daily_total_data

Comment: added a link to sample project to the answer. Check that

Answer (score 2):

GoogleApiClient is deprecated according to the new updates. As well as the HistoryApi is also deprecated. So first have to use the GoogleSignInAccount instead of GoogleApiClient and also use HistoryClient of Google Fit instead of HistoryApi.

Setting Fitness Options

```
 val fitnessOptions: GoogleSignInOptionsExtension = FitnessOptions.builder()
        .addDataType(TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ).build()
```

Setting Google SignIn Option

```
val googleSignInOptions =
        GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .addExtension(fitnessOptions).requestEmail().build()
    val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireActivity(), googleSignInOptions)
    val signIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signIntent, 0)
```

Getting Account

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        if (account != null) {
            getGoogleFitData(account)
        }
    }
}
```

Now for getting step data

```
val response: Task<DataReadResponse> =
            Fitness.getHistoryClient(mContext, mSignInAccount)
                .readData(
                    DataReadRequest.Builder()
                        .read(TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                        .setTimeRange(
                            startTime,
                            endTime,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                        )
                        .build()
                )

        val readDataResult: DataReadResponse? = Tasks.await(response)
        val dataSet: DataSet = readDataResult!!.getDataSet(TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)

        var total = 0
        if (!dataSet.isEmpty) {
            val dataPoints = dataSet.dataPoints
            if (dataPoints.size > 0) {
                for (i in 0 until dataPoints.size) {
                    total += dataSet.dataPoints[i].getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt()
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "Total Steps : $total")
            }
        }
```

- Here startTime and endTime are timemills of any date and time.

Thank You.

Comment: Yes sure. I've updated my answer check it out you definitely find some solution. Thanks

Comment: Thanks mate. could you check this once and see if you have any clue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65933509/runtime-error-while-accessing-google-api-in-android-emulator

Comment: I've replied in your question please check it.

Comment: Thanks bro!! I have entered data manually in my google fit app. But my History API data point values seems to return empty. Even if I add any data it doesn't reflect in the google fit app. is there some sync option I am missing??