# runtime error while accessing google api in android emulator

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-api, google-fit

I am trying to access the googleFit API.
It seems pretty straightforward. Get the google sign-in permissions and required authorizations then query for Step count.
My code doesn't seem to work.
When I debug this the fitnessOption declaration part throws **"source code doesn't match byte code"** error. I cleaned my project, rebuild it it didn't work
Android gurus, Where am I going wrong??

```
fun getAuthorizationAndReadData() {
        try {
            MainActivity().fitSignIn(FitActionRequestCode.READ_DATA)
        } catch () {
           Log.i("e", "error!!!!")
        }
       }
```

MainActivity

```
enum class FitActionRequestCode {
    READ_DATA
}

private val fitnessOptions: GoogleSignInOptionsExtension = FitnessOptions.builder()
            .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ).build()

    fun fitSignIn(requestCode: FitActionRequestCode) {
        if (oAuthPermissionsApproved()) {
            readHistoryData()
        } else {
            requestCode.let {
                GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        requestCode.ordinal,
                        getGoogleAccount(), fitnessOptions)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getGoogleAccount() = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions)


    private fun oAuthPermissionsApproved() = GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(getGoogleAccount(), fitnessOptions)

    private fun performActionForRequestCode(requestCode: FitActionRequestCode) = when (requestCode) {
        FitActionRequestCode.READ_DATA -> readHistoryData()
    }
    private fun readHistoryData(): Task<DataReadResponse> {
        // Begin by creating the query.
        val readRequest = queryFitnessData()

        // Invoke the History API to fetch the data with the query
        return Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
                .readData(readRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener { dataReadResponse ->
                    printData(dataReadResponse)
                    Log.i(ContentValues.TAG, "Data read was successful!") }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "There was a problem reading the data.", e)
                }
    }

    private fun queryFitnessData(): DataReadRequest {
        // [START build_read_data_request]
        // Setting a start and end date using a range of 1 week before this moment.
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
        val now = Date()
        calendar.time = now
        val endTime = calendar.timeInMillis
        calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1)
        val startTime = calendar.timeInMillis

        return DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps once.

Click Build -> Clean then Disable Instant Run, in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment